# What does the phrase "half seven" mean?

Tags: idioms, british-english, time

I've heard the British term "half seven" (or "half nine," "half five", etc) used to tell time. I can't remember though if it means 6:30 or 7:30 (i.e. half *an hour before* seven, or half *past* seven)?

I'm American and have never heard another American use the phrase, but apparently it's very common in the UK.

Comment: When I first moved from the UK to the US, I was still getting acclimatized to the American dialect. I remember someone asked me the time and I said "half six", and he responded "you mean three?" However, what goes around comes around. Later I asked him the time, and he said "quarter of four", to which I responded "You mean one?"

Comment: Related: [What does 'ten of six' mean in regard to time](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/what-does-ten-of-six-mean-in-regard-to-time), in which the top answer actually mentions and explains "half six".

Comment: I think the difference between the English and German, (et. Al.) makes sense when you think about the difference in the order noun and verb relationships differ.
Dutch Pa. "Throw the horse over the fence some hay." might help put it into a larger perspective...

Comment: nice, so half seven actually is the same time as halfzeven in dutch or halbseben in german.....taking into account the time difference.. haha.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

*Half seven* is the same as *half past seven*, with *past* simply missing. It's **7:30**.

Comment: Unlike German, where "halb sieben" would mean 6:30.

Comment: In Dutch, "half zeven" is 6:30 as well.

Comment: That's weird that it's the opposite in other languages, but it makes sense because it sounds like it could be either one. It's not very intuitive.

Comment: Swedish is the same too. "Halv sju" (half seven) is taken as 6:30. Does that mean 06:30 or 18:30? Absent context, no one knows.

Answer (score 17):

Americans say "half *past* seven".  I've never heard anyone say "half *before* seven" nor have I heard an American say "*half seven*".  It does lead to odd situations.  My German wife has a very good English friend.  She learned the difference between "half seven" and "*halbsieben*" when they both showed up on time yet an hour apart.