# Time format "10 to 10"

Tags: meaning, time

Can someone tell what does this time format "10 to 10" mean? Is it 9:50 or 10:10?

Comment: See too http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/what-does-ten-of-six-mean-in-regard-to-time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The time "10 to 10" may also be stated as "10 minutes of 10", meaning 9:50.  (From [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=minutes+of+10%2Cminutes+to+10&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for *minutes of 10,minutes to 10*,  the "*to 10*" form occurs several times as frequently as the "*of 10*" form.)

The last two examples on the "[telling_time](http://www.eslgold.com/speaking/telling_time.html)" webpage at eslgold.com illustrate the conventional meaning of *x minutes to y*:

> 10:45  = It's ten forty-five. = It's [a] quarter to eleven.
>   
> 8:35 = It's eight thirty-five. = It's twenty-five minutes to nine.