# Meaning of "10 of 8"?

Tags: time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does 'ten of six' mean in regard to time?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/what-does-ten-of-six-mean-in-regard-to-time)

In a [Family Guy episode](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:vQafDqTRnbQJ:notabenoid.com/book/16882/55575/original?format=m&enc=0&crlf=2%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&lr=lang_en) (The Hand That Rocks The Wheelchair), Meg asks "is it 10 of 8?", apparently looking up at the clock and referring to the fact that the time is 7:50.  Is this a commonly used term to refer to the time as being "10 minutes to 8", or is it just a Family Guy thing?  If it's common (I've never heard it before), what does it stand for, if "10 to 8" stands for "10 minutes to 8"?

Comment: It is common.  It means the same as "10 to 8".  Or "10 till 8".  And many more...

Comment: As you've just realised: [What does 'ten of six' mean in regard to time?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/what-does-ten-of-six-mean-in-regard-to-time)

Comment: Yep.  Voted to close. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary.com has an entry specifically for this meaning:

> [**of**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/of?s=t)    13. *Chiefly Northern U.S.* before the hour of; until: *twenty minutes of five.*

I don't have any proof, but it seems like the full phrase could have originally been *10 minutes short of 8 o'clock* or perhaps *10 minutes shy of 8 o'clock*.  Over time, words could have been dropped in a progression similar to the following:

*10 minutes short of 8*

*10 minutes of 8*

*10 of 8*

The meaning is still unambiguous as long as you understand the omitted words.

Comment: It means absolutely nothing in the UK, though.

Answer (score 0):

It was definitely a more common expression when I was a kid (I mean in the '60s and '70s) before there were digital clocks (or before they were in common use).